# Why devnet is not working?

Tags: devnet

I developing on Solana's devnet, Sometimes transaction processing doesn't work on devnet (also on mainnet), why is this happening?

What is the problem?

If it's a core issue with the chain, I'm curious to know what's going wrong that's causing the chain to die. :'(

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Devnet is doing fine, and this is just a graphical bug on the explorer(ping api is down)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% to this cause the die of the network, but I found an article about it: https://cryptoslate.com/solana-outage-was-caused-by-infinite-loop-bug-previously-seen-on-devnet/
Does anybody knows something about the chain? When will it start again?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The article talks about the mainnet outage that occurred recently.